# Magento 2 Design Configuration error

Tags: javascript, magento

I am trying to open the Design configuration in Magento 2 but it entered in infinite loop of loading,and when i inspect the page i got this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor` in layout.js:66,can anyone help me in that?

> Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor
>       at Object.initComponent (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.js:66:25)
>       at fire (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3099:30)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3211:7)
>       at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3301:34)
>       at fire (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3099:30)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3211:7)
>       at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) [as resolve] (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3301:34)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.js:59:20
>       at Object.execCb (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:33)
>       at Object.context.execCb (http://127.0.0.1:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1493554470/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/resolver.js:131:31)

Comment: you can check the https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/uncaught-typeerror-constr-is-not-a-constructor-error-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you website deploy is not properly completed. Use the below commond and deploy again:

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade   //(only for new extensin)
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 7777 var pub
```